# Docker: Error response from daemon: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, artifactory

My company uses Artifactory to store it's artifacts and I was getting this error when I tried to pull down the image.

When I run `docker compose up -d` I got the error, `Error response from daemon: unauthorized: The client does not have permission for manifest`

I have no idea what to do with this. I was directed to this article but it didn't do anything: [K8s Image Pull from Private Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65989669/k8s-image-pull-from-private-artifactory/65996166#65996166)
and
https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/1420

But still didn't work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turned out I needed to run the command `docker login -u your-username@your-domain.com your-company-or-project-docker.jfrog.io`

Then you put in your Artifactory apikey as the password.

Comment: Actually this syntax did not work for me, I mean the '@' between the username and the server hostname seems to be an invalid syntax. See `docker help login`. So this worked instead : `docker login -u your-username docker-registry-hostname`.
(We have internally hosted artifactory servers, so generalized the hostname for simplicity.)
Once I corrected the syntax, in my case the login worked both with my corporate password as well of the "identity token" I created. (I guess there may be some LDAP based integration in our case.)

Answer (score 3):

It could also be that you do not have the permission to access this image (its *manifest*). So check your access rights.